# Long beep in vb 2010

Tags: .net, vb.net, beep

In vb6 i used

`beep (1000,2000)`

Which means

```
Beep(frequency, duration)
```

How to make a long beep in vb 2010, because obviously doesn't support this version.

Comment: Could you explain why `Console.Beep(1000, 2000);` won't work? Or you're not aware of that?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel becase [Beep in VB.Net doesn't take any parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/kz27k38z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: @Psychemaster I don't get it, You linked to VB functions documentation. I'm talking about [Console.Beep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fe3hdb1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @Psychemaster just like that. And how to take a long beep then .

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Maybe that should be an answer, provided you also post a link to the relevant documentation!

Comment: @SriramSakthivel that was the solution for now. You can post it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless am missing something obvious you're simply looking for [Console.Beep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fe3hdb1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. Its signature is as follows

```
public static void Beep(int frequency, int duration)
```

You'll call it as

```
Console.Beep(1000,2000)
```

I believe that's what you're after.

**Note:** Documentation mentions a caveat that *The Beep method is not supported on the 64-bit editions of Windows Vista and Windows XP.* I thought worth adding it here.